# Postgres not using index when ORDER BY and LIMIT when LIMIT above X

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have been trying to debug an issue with postgres where it decides to not use an index when LIMIT is above a specific value.

For example I have a table of 150k rows and when searching with LIMIT of 286 it uses the index while with LIMIT above 286 it does not.

LIMIT 286 uses index

```sql
db=# explain (analyze, buffers) SELECT * FROM tempz.tempx AS r INNER JOIN tempz.tempy AS z ON (r.id_tempy=z.id) WHERE z.int_col=2000 AND z.string_col='temp_string' ORDER BY r.name ASC, r.type ASC, r.id ASC LIMIT 286;
                                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.56..5024.12 rows=286 width=810) (actual time=0.030..0.992 rows=286 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=921
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.56..16968.23 rows=966 width=810) (actual time=0.030..0.977 rows=286 loops=1)
         Join Filter: (r.id_tempy = z.id)
         Rows Removed by Join Filter: 624
         Buffers: shared hit=921
         ->  Index Scan using tempz_tempx_name_type_id_idx on tempx r  (cost=0.42..14357.69 rows=173878 width=373) (actual time=0.016..0.742 rows=910 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=919
         ->  Materialize  (cost=0.14..2.37 rows=1 width=409) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=910)
               Buffers: shared hit=2
               ->  Index Scan using tempy_string_col_idx on tempy z  (cost=0.14..2.37 rows=1 width=409) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (string_col = 'temp_string'::text)
                     Filter: (int_col = 2000)
                     Buffers: shared hit=2
 Planning Time: 0.161 ms
 Execution Time: 1.032 ms
(16 rows)
```

vs.

LIMIT 287 doing sort

```sql
db=# explain (analyze, buffers) SELECT * FROM tempz.tempx AS r INNER JOIN tempz.tempy AS z ON (r.id_tempy=z.id) WHERE z.int_col=2000 AND z.string_col='temp_string' ORDER BY r.name ASC, r.type ASC, r.id ASC LIMIT 287;
                                                                         QUERY PLAN                                                                          
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=4976.86..4977.58 rows=287 width=810) (actual time=49.802..49.828 rows=287 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=37154
   ->  Sort  (cost=4976.86..4979.27 rows=966 width=810) (actual time=49.801..49.813 rows=287 loops=1)
         Sort Key: r.name, r.type, r.id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 506kB
         Buffers: shared hit=37154
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..4932.59 rows=966 width=810) (actual time=0.020..27.973 rows=51914 loops=1)
               Buffers: shared hit=37154
               ->  Seq Scan on tempy z  (cost=0.00..12.70 rows=1 width=409) (actual time=0.006..0.008 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((int_col = 2000) AND (string_col = 'temp_string'::text))
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 2
                     Buffers: shared hit=1
               ->  Index Scan using tempx_id_tempy_idx on tempx r  (cost=0.42..4340.30 rows=57959 width=373) (actual time=0.012..17.075 rows=51914 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (id_tempy = z.id)
                     Buffers: shared hit=37153
 Planning Time: 0.258 ms
 Execution Time: 49.907 ms
(17 rows)
```

**Update:**

This is Postgres 11 and `VACUUM ANALYZE` is run daily. Also, I have already tried to use CTE to remove the filter but the problem is the sorting specifically

```sql
->  Sort  (cost=4976.86..4979.27 rows=966 width=810) (actual time=49.801..49.813 rows=287 loops=1)
         Sort Key: r.name, r.type, r.id
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 506kB
         Buffers: shared hit=37154
```

**Update 2:**

After running `VACUUM ANALYZE` the database starts using the index for some hours and then it goes back to not using it.

Comment: Have you run [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html) on the involved tables lately?

Comment: You can disable enable scanning for you session using `SET enable_seqscan = OFF`, try it and view explain analyze result.

Comment: It is using the plan it thinks will be faster.  It is wrong, but of course it is wrong.  Estimation is hard.  Is it wrong enough that it is actually causing a problem?

Comment: 50 sec of execution time may be a problem indeed ... As the filter condition is only on the `tempy` table, you can try to force the index scan on this table first with a CTE :  `WITH list AS (SELECT * FROM tempy WHERE int_col=2000 AND string_col='temp_string') SELECT * FROM list AS z INNER JOIN tempx AS r ON r.id_tempy=z.id ORDER BY r.name ASC, r.type ASC, r.id ASC LIMIT 287`

Comment: @Edouar,  Except it is `~50 milliseconds` which is `0.05` seconds

Comment: This is an example query. For some results it can take up to 6 minutes instead of 100ms if it is using the index.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver On the local database running `VACUUM ANALYZE` made it to start using the index. In production database I am not sure we can run `ANALYZE` as it locks the whole table and might cause an incident.


@RaminFaracov `SET enable_seqscan = OFF` does not change the planner. The issue appears the moment it decides to sort instead of using the index.


@Edouard I already tried doing this with a CTE and the planner still does sorting on the tempx table

Comment: @AdrianKlaver just checked and autovaccum and autoanalyze is run daily but the issue persists unfortunately

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need to see your table definitions and your index definitions as well as the output of EXPLAIN, from your *production* tables. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: Per [ANALYZE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-analyze.html): *ANALYZE requires only a read lock on the target table, so it can run in parallel with other activity on the table.*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I can force Postgres to avoid doing any sort if I run `SET enable_sort TO OFF;`. This raises the cost of sorting very high which causes the Postgres planner to do index scan instead.

I am not really sure why Postgres thinks that index scan is so costly `cost=0.42..14357.69` and thinks sorting is cheaper and ends up choosing that. It is also very weird that immediately after a `VACUUM ANALYZE` it analyzes the costs correctly but after some hours it goes back to sorting.

With sort off plan is still not optimized as it does `materialize` and loads stuff into memory but it is still faster than sorting.